# how to check an existing 'tarificationtache'

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an interface of 'tarificationtache' in this interface the 'technicien' can have pricing for its 'taches' and for each 'tache' a single 'tarif',
I would like to check if this 'tache' it has a 'tarif' for this 'technicien' if yes it retur a message 'tarifi exist' if it creates it .

**table tarificationtaches**

```
Schema::create('tarificationtaches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->float('tarif', 8,2);
        $table->integer('tache_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('tache_id')->references('id')->on('taches');
        $table->integer('technicien_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('technicien_id')->references('id')- 
        >on('techniciens');
        $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
 @if(count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <ul>
    @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
     <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    </div>
 @endif
 <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var getMetiersByTechnicienUrl = "{{url('/metiersbytechnicien')}}";
    var getTachesByMetierUrl = "{{url('/tachesbymetier')}}";
    //console.log(getMetiersByTechnicienUrl,getTachesByMetierUrl, 
     getTarificationsByTacheUrl);
    function getMetiersByTechnicien(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var technicien_id = val;
            $.get(getMetiersByTechnicienUrl+'/'+technicien_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value=">-Select-"</option>' ;
                $.each(res.metiers,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
   value="'+item.id+'">'+item.libelle_metier+'</option>';
                });
                $('#metiers').html(html);

            });
        }
    }




    function getTachesByMetier(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var metier_id = val;
            $.get(getTachesByMetierUrl+'/'+metier_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.taches,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
  value="'+item.id+'">'+item.libelle_tache+'</option>';
                });
                $('#taches').html(html);

            });
        }
    }
    </script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">

       <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Tarification tache</h1>
        <form action=" {{url ('tarification')  }}" method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="technicien">Technicien</label>
               <select onchange="getMetiersByTechnicien(this.value)" 
  name="technicien_id" 
                  id="technicien_id" class="form-control">
                       <option value="">-Select-</option>
                       @foreach($technicien as $t)
                              <option value="{{$t->id }}" {{ $t->id == 
 $technicien_id ? 'selected = "selected"' 
                              : '' }}>
                                    {{$t->user->nom}}
                              </option>
                       @endforeach
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
<label>Metier: </label>
<select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" style="width: 
200px" class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
@foreach($metiers as $metier)
      <option value={{$metier->id}}>{{$metier->libelle_metier}}</option>
@endforeach
 </select>
        </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>tache: </label>
                        <select style="width: 200px" class="productname form- 
 control" 
    name="tache_id" id="taches">
                            <option value="">-Select-</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>tarification: </label>
                        <input style="width: 200px" class="productname form- 
 control" type="text"  
     name ="Tarif" class="form-control" value="{{old('tarif')}}">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form- 
 control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <link 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap- 
    datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap- 
     datepicker.js"></script>
   @endsection
```

**controller**

```
 public function create($technicien_id)   
{
    $technicien = technicien::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $taches = Tache::orderBy('libelle_tache', 'asc')->get();
    $metiers = Metier::orderBy('libelle_metier', 'asc')->get();
    return view('tarification.create')->with('taches', $taches)- 
    >with('technicien', $technicien)- 
    >with('metiers', $metiers)->with('technicien_id', $technicien_id);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $tarification = new tarificationtache();
    $tarification ->tache_id = $request->input('tache_id');
    $tarification ->Tarif =$request->input('Tarif');
    $tarification->technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
    $tarification->save();

    return redirect('technicien');  }
```